# How to open a browser on notification click in Android?

Tags: android

This is my code, I want to open a URL when user clicks on notification.

This is the code:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(link));

Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setLargeIcon(remote_picture)
                    .setContentTitle(onvan)
                    .setContentIntent(notificationIntent)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setStyle(notiStyle)
                    .build();
notificationManager.notify(1, myNotification);
```

I got this error :
The method `setContentIntent(PendingIntent)` in the type `NotificationCompat.Builder` is not applicable for the arguments (Intent)

What am I doing wrong? How can I tell it to open browser when user clicks on the notification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add pending intent to the the notification.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(link));

PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
myNotification.setContentIntent(pending);
```